# PowerShell complex -replace

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, how do you replace:

```
Session("*Logging")="true"
```

to

```
Session("*Logging")="false"
```

The following PowerShell script doesn't work.

```
get-content E:\WebSystems\Web1\web.config -replace "Session("*Logging")="true"", "Session("*Logging")="false"" | set-content E:\WebSystems\Web1\web.config
```

It says a bunch of errors:

You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '*' operator.

Unexpected token ... in expression or statement.

Missing argument in parameter list.

Comment: Is this a string literal: `Session("*Logging")="true"`? `-replace` uses regex to find matches and `*` is a special character that needs to be escaped

Answer (score 3):

If `Session("*Logging")="true"` is a string literal then some of the characters would needed to be escaped for the match to work. `-replace` uses regex for string matching and the brackets and astericks have special functions. One thing you could do is use the static method `[regex]::escape` to do the hard work for you. Other issues are that you need to enclose the `Get-Content` in brackets else it will treat `-replace` as a parameter to `Get-Content`. Also the string are not escaped properly which is what would cause most of your syntax errors. In the variables below I enclose the string in single quotes which is one of several approaches for addressing this.

```
$match = [regex]::escape('Session("*Logging")="true"')
$replace = 'Session("*Logging")="false"'

(get-content E:\WebSystems\Web1\web.config) -replace $match, $replace | ....
```

The escaped string looks like `Session\("\*Logging"\)="true"`. You dont need to work about special characters for the replacement string itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your string quoting is mashed, "Session(" is a string, then *Logging falls outside a string, and PowerShell is trying to deal with it as a multiplication or similar.

If you fixed the quoting, you'd then need to escape Regex special characters to use them as string literals.

And if you fix that, I end up with an error saying `get-content` doesn't take a `-replace` parameter.

How about something like:

```
#short commandlet nanmes
(gc E:\WebSystems\Web1\web.config) |% { $_.replace('Session("*Logging")="true"', 'Session("*Logging")="false"') } | sc E:\WebSystems\Web1\web.config

#long form commandlet names
(Get-Content E:\WebSystems\Web1\web.config) |foreach { $_.Replace('Session("*Logging")="true"', 'Session("*Logging")="false"') } | Set-Content E:\WebSystems\Web1\web.config
```

This uses foreach to gain access to the string.replace() method, which uses string literals and avoids having to deal with regex escapes, uses single quotes to have a string with double quotes in it, and wraps get-content in parentheses so it reads all content and closes the file and doesn't clash with set-content.

Comment: Piping into ForEach is not required ... this would work `(get-content 'C:\temp\new  2.txt') -replace "ABC", "CBA" | Set-Content c:\temp\newer.txt`. Looks like we noticed all the same things

Comment: @Matt Piping into ForEach isn't required for a solution, but doing it gives access to $_.replace() which is a different Replace method, one that doesn't deal with Regexes, so the regex character escaping stops mattering.

Comment: You could still have done `(gc E:\WebSystems\Web1\web.config).Replace('Session("*Logging")="true"', 'Session("*Logging")="false"')`. Just presenting the option is all

Comment: @Matt, I didn't think of that. That's neater.